# is there a tex font set for this kind of curly alphabet?

Tags: math-mode, fonts

the symbols comes from this [post](http://www.ee.columbia.edu/~vittorio/Glossary.pdf)

[image]

is there a tex font set for this kind of curly alphabet?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It looks like `eulervm` with `\mathcal`: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{eulervm}
\begin{document}
$\mathcal{F}_n and \mathcal{G}_n$
\end{document}`

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik thanks man, plz move or copy your comments to answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The font is the caligraphic font from the Euler Virtual Fonts ([`eulervm`](https://ctan.org/pkg/eulervm)). If you load the `eulervm` package the text looks quite similar to the screenshot:

> [image]

However the subscript `n` from the linked PDF doesn't look like Euler's, but Computer Modern. You can load Euler for the `\mathcal` alphabet only with `\usepackage[cal=euler]{mathalpha}` (notice the difference of the subscript `n`):

> [image]

Code:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=4cm]{geometry}
% \usepackage{eulervm}
\usepackage[cal=euler]{mathalpha}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{description}
  \item [Hypothesis Space] Term used in the machine learning literature.
    It denotes the space $\mathcal{F}_n$ of classifiers, or the space
    $\mathcal{G}_n$ of conditional probabilities, from which the learning
    algorithm selects a hypothesis.
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It *is* the same, well done! Off-topic. How did you produce LaTeX text without background? In imgur it is a png image, but it seems that you have compiled it using svg extension, which I love.

Comment: @manooooh I compiled a normal pdf and used ImageMagick: `convert -trim -density 150 texsx.pdf texsx.png`. The PDF doesn't actually have a background color, so ImageMagick doesn't add one when converting to png.

Comment: +1. :-) Another way to load the Euler math-calligraphic letters without changing the other math fonts is to run `\usepackage[cal=euler]{mathalfa}` in the preamble. I find this a bit more mnemonic than `\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathcal}{U}{eus}{m}{n}`. :-)

Comment: @Mico I didn't know of `mathalfa` (which actually just redirects to `mathalpha`). Indeed, much easier to remember. Thanks :-)

Comment: You can also load the OpenType font Neo Euler in `unicode-math`. It contains the same `\mathcal` alphabet.